# WPF App and Neo4j Client always throws me a 404

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

Im using the neo4j Client v4.0.0.1 and want to create just a single node from a class but Im always getting the following 404 error.

Error Code:

```
System.Exception: 'Received an unexpected HTTP status when executing the request.

The response status was: 404 Not Found

The response from Neo4j (which might include useful detail!) was: '
```

If I use curl to check if all is fine:

```
curl -I localhost:7474
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Feb 2020 14:23:18 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 223
```

And:

```
curl -I http://localhost:7474/db/data
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 25 Feb 2020 14:23:26 GMT
Location: http://localhost:7474/db/data/
Content-Length: 0
```

all seems to be fine. Thats my try Id like to start with:

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

private void createNode(){
            var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data/"), "neo4j", "neo4j");

        client.Connect();

        var results = client.Cypher
                    .Create("(n:Person)")
                    .Return((a) => new {
                        Person = a.As<Person>()
                    }).Results;

    }
```

Comment: Hey CodeCase - What version of Neo4j?

Comment: Its the 4.Version.

Comment: It won't work with v4 at the moment, you could try the bolt version, but the http doesn't

Comment: Ok thank you, is there any plan to get that working in v4?

Comment: Plans, but no time frame, basically it's when I can, I am working on it though

Comment: Im new to neo4j but liketo help if I can.

Comment: I would use the older version of the client, with the `BoltGraphClient` instead

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Neo4j driver. I'm not sure that neo4j client .net library has support with Neo4j 4.0. Also, you can return to 3.5 version